# db scheme for persistent login

Tags: php

I want to compare the key of a cookie with a key found in the database so as to let a returning visitor login to the site automatically,this means that the key in the db and the cookie will be associated with a specific user.

My question is what is better, storing the key to a table where the username is stored along 
with their password, or create a separate table there will be the username with the associated key and timestamp of course.

Complexity is an issue here-furthermore I am trying to find a if innodb or Isam is better for the above.

What complicates the matter more  is the fact that it is difficult to project from now
how big the application is going to be and how that might impact the design of the database.
The sooner I come to a sound solution the better

Comment: just store the username/password in the cookie and check that with the username/password in db..why creating another column/table!?

Comment: @BhuvanRikka Don't store the password in a cookie!

Comment: okay,then the username would be fine

Comment: may be you can store hash of username in cookie and check when user come to your site.

Comment: Normally a sound method is to store instead a ranodmly generated token and store this with the user row. Comparing the two on the users return. Be aware of cookie hijacking, you will need to combat that, a good starting point is: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html

Comment: sounds like a hackers dreamwebsite, it means that i can steal and still use expired cookies, you shouldn't do this.
bad security practice

Comment: What you would recommend as a good security practice?

Comment: @pyruva Tbh anyone who doesn't expire cookies and check their expiry upon usage should really go back to school. That is kinda like the fundamental of web security. Infact I think the OP intended the tiemstamp to be used for that reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to answer this with some thoughts and ideas on how to approach this.

Now what you should consider first when doing this is how other site do it:

- Amazon allow you to browse the site under a persistent cookie however they do not allow the placing of orders or the changing of details without being forced to login again. However that being said this still has a serious security flaw. If you allow one click ordering and then some one else uses your computer and clicks on a link in a campaign email from Amazon (an Ad for example) there is still a chance that the order can be placed on the other guys account without having to actually be logged in (yep I found this out by accident, thankfully).
- Facebook takes a similar approach to Amazon. From personal experience I think they demand a relogin every two days to edit account details etc.
- Stackoverflow from what I can gather has no such security measures. Once you are logged in your logged in for a specified duration.
- Google houses a 2+ year cookie and once every week or so asks you to re-login to validate yourself.

So as you can see many sites do not just allow persistent logins to control their user interactions and actually a returning persistent login rare even logs a person in fully. Instead what most sites implement is a 2 tier system of login where by you can view the site as the cookie user however you cannot edit anything without having to login again.

You will immediately notice once thing here. Many of these sites do not care for cookie expiration only for browser session expiration. Persistent cookies rarely have a short term expiration so this point is kind of useless. As @pyruva states it is easy to steal someones cookie and view a site as them, this happens on Facebook all the time (you can even find video tutorials on how to do it).

So the first thing to remember is that a persistent login, by nature, is insecure. The way to make it secure is normally within your application logic by implementing something such as a 2 tier authentication system.

The one thing you should never do is store some personally identifiable information about the user within that cookie such as the username or password, even in hashed form. A better way is to use a randomly generated token (think of OAuth2 here) to handshake with the server initially.

Of course one other thing you will need to consider is protecting your cookies in general. You can find a lot of resources on Google about this however here is one link that should help a lot: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html

So hopefully that should give you some direction and hints on how to tackle this.

#### Edit

Every user that comes to your site has effectively two sessions when it comes to cookies. They have a browser session which, when the browser is closed, will delete the cookies from their browser (normally denoted as 0 expire time within HTTP headers).

Then there is the persistent session. The one you are tying to implement now, where cookies can last years before they actually expire.

This is what I mean by browser expiration. So most sites house temporary cookies which will be removed once you close the browser. These cookies are normally used to keep your session yours.

If sites cared about cookie expiration then they wouldn't house cookies which are valid for 2 years on your computer. Let's face it if some one is gonna use expired cookies to abuse your account they are kinda out of luck since the cookies are still perfectly valid. This is a greater security threat but it does prove my point.

Comment: Yes, your post was very helpful. I could many question...but I am going to focus on one(for now-for other question I might post other more specific questions). You said that many of the sites you mention above do not care for cookie expiration only for browser session expiration. This, I do not understand.Can you elaborate a little? How is it that these sites do not care about cookie expiration, since, these sites, as far as I know, use all of them persistent cookies.

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou Ok added a bit of a edit, hopefully clears things up

Comment: Ok, I fully understood that distinction about session cookies and cookies for persistent logins. I want to focus to your last paragraph.How an expired cookie(I assume you are referring to persistent cookies here) can be valid? You said that persistent cookies are a threat. Then how  is it and some site use 2-year cookie if as you say pose a threat? I miss something here.

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou A cookie must be classed as expired by your app otherwise some one could manipulate the cookies expiration time to use old data to get through your system. Tokens help here renewing every time a new cookie is set as such invalidating the contents of the old cookie and so expiring it within your app. As to why sites use it...well it is user friendly. At the end of the day you either try your best to combat the security needs of your user base or you combat their usability needs...

Comment: As db development now goes, I have created a table named "credentials" where username and password are stored, and the cookie token will just go to the session table. So far I have concluded in the aforementioned scheme-nonetheless I do not rule out a change in the aforementioned scheme happening in the future.